# Sharing UnitOfWork across Linq2SQL and Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-sql, unit-of-work

I am considering using Nhibernate for new work in an application that is already using Linq2SQL, is it possible to use the 2 technologies side by side sharing the same Unit of Work?

Abit more background if you want it....

I am working on a web application that could be called 'enterprise' in terms of size, there are circa 400 tables,  the site gets millions of hits a month, but the business logic isn't particularly complicated.

The site uses Linq2Sql and everything works fine, but as you would expect this has had the effect of making the 'domain' closely related to the database.

I have suggested introducing NHibernate, but people rightfully say this would be an expensive exercise to replace something that is working?

Comment: What are your arguments from changing LINQ to SQL to NHibernate? What features are you missing? And why changing to NHibernate instead of Entity Framework? Migrating L2S to EF would be easier than migrating to NHib.

Comment: @steven because I have used Nhibernate heavily before. Nhibnerate allows for a proper domain that is not a one to one mapping of the db, it has proper POCOs, it has a larger community behind it and is generally a more sophisticated tool.

Comment: All your arguments (except that you used it before) also hold for Entity Framework. I'm not convinced :-)

Comment: @Steve Maybe your right. But it don't really answer my question. Can I share a unit of work across Linq2SQL and EF4/Nhib?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I think wrapping them in one UoW could be complicated. I wouldn't go that way. Create two UoWs and wrap them in a single transaction.

Answer (score 2):

If it ain't broke, why fix it?  You say that the business logic is not complicated, so does it really matter if Linq2Sql is making your domain model more data-oriented than you would like? Would a relatively simple domain really benefit from a more pure OOP approach? Personally I would leave it as it was, at least until there was a real business case for changing technologies.  Think of the cost/benefit.

Comment: Sure. This a side, your not really answering my question.